# does "Ignoring APKINDEX" mean the image does not install apk search command tool?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to use this docker image [big-data-europe/docker-spark](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark), based on "Alpine Linux v3.8"

when I try to search `sbt`

```
apk search sbt
```

I got

```
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.adfa7ceb.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.efaa1f73.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

does this mean the image does not install apk search command tool?

Comment: That error indicates the package indexes are missing, did you run `apk update` first?

Answer (score 1):

agree with @GracefulRestart

it seems that you forgot to run `apk update` first.